# .Net WebClient Fails Silently when Lacking Permissions

Tags: .net, webclient

[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) is failing silently (not throwing an Exception) when asked to download a file to a folder where the process has no write permission:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(url, outputPath);
}
if (!File.Exists(outputPath)) logger.Warn("Could not download file.");
```

The code was running in a once-a-minute loop in a Windows Service running under LOCAL SERVICE, trying to write to a folder where permissions had been removed.  The moment I restored appropriate permissions on the target folder, the download started succeeding.

Is this a known behavior?  Is it a bug?  Is checking for the existence of the output file the correct way to determine whether DownloadFile was successful?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a known behavior?

No. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx):

> When using this method in a middle tier application, such as an
>   ASP.NET page, you will receive an error if the account under which the
>   application executes does not have permission to access the file.

So basically you will get an exception if the account you are running this code under doesn't have write permission to the target folder.

---

> Is it a bug?

I don't think so.

---

> Is checking for the existence of the output file the correct way to
>   determine whether DownloadFile was successful?

No, because if you don't have permission to the given folder, [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) will return false as the documentation explicitly states:

> If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the
>   specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false
>   regardless of the existence of path.

So you probably messed up something with the permissions. For example if you have write permission to the folder but no read permission, `DownloadFile` will succeed but File.Exists will return false.

Comment: "So basically you will get an exception if the account you are running this code under doesn't have write permission to the target folder."... the service was running as LOCAL SYSTEM, LOCAL SYSTEM had no permission at all to the folder, and I did not receive an Exception.

Comment: I'll try to re-create the issue with an isolated test.